# Relation between Terminal Voltage and EMF of a cell while the cell is being charged

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I know the relation between the terminal voltage, V and emf of the cell, V' **while charging** given by

V = V' + Ir

where I = Current in the circuit and r = Internal Resistance of Cell

Can anyone please explain why in charging a cell, the sign changes from **-** (which is when the cell discharges) to **+**  in detail **by deriving the formula** ?

Thanx in advance

---

@Farcher Can u explain/deduce that formula(V = V' + Ir) on the basis of following diagram:-

[image]

The diagram shows a cell of emf, V' and internal resistance, r being charged up by a charger.

Comment: The left hand side of the charger is positive and the right hand is negative. Starting at the top right hand corner and applying Kirchhoff's voltage law one gets $V-V'-Ir=0$ Which when rearranged gives you the required result.

Answer (score 4):

To drive a current through a ideal cell (no internal resistance) from its positive terminal to its negative terminal requires there to be an external voltage source which exceeds the emf of the cell $\mathcal E$ by an infinitesimal amount.
However with a cell that has internal resistance $R$ an extra potential difference must be applied across the cell terminals to drive the current $I$ through the internal resistance $=IR$.

So the total applied potential difference across the cell must be $V = \mathcal E + IR$.

It might be clearer if both sides of the equation are multiplied by the current $VI = \mathcal E I +I^2R$.

Now $VI$ is the power being delivered by an external source to the cell.
$I^2R$ is the rate at which heat is produced due to the cell having an internal resistance.
$\mathcal EI$ is the rate at which energy is being supplied to the cell to reverse the chemical change which the cell uses when it is discharging (converting chemical energy into electrical energy.

Now doing the same when the terminal potential difference is less than the emf of the cell.

$V= \mathcal E - IR \Rightarrow VI = \mathcal E I - I^2R \Rightarrow \mathcal E I = VI + I^2R$

$\mathcal E I$ is the electrical power supplied by the cell from the chemical reaction within the cell.
$I^2R$ is again the rate at which heat is produced due to the cell having an internal resistance.
$VI$ is the power delivered to the external circuit by the cell.

So in one case (discharging)  the cell is producing the electrical energy from chemical energy and in the other case (recharging) the cell is consuming electrical energy which is being converted into chemical energy.

Comment: I have added some more things in the post. Please Check it out. Hoping you will answer. Thanx and sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: can i consider terminal voltage to be equal to EMF of a NON-IDEAL CELL when it is kept in an open circuit?

Comment: KES because the current is then zero and so the voltage drop across the internal resistance $IR$ is also zero.

Comment: I am really very sorry but there's one more doubt. The formula ,V=V'+Ir is valid for an empty cell or for an fully charged-up cell. Can u please explain. I am asking this as there is one question related to it in which a cell having emf of 12V is connected to dc charger having emf of 110V and it's asking about the cell terminal voltage. So what is not seeming right to me in this question is that if the cell has 12V emf(which i think it means it is fullcharged) across it, how will it be charged more?

Comment: In a problem such as this you have to assume that the emf of the cell is independent of the state of charge of the cell.  In other words there are still chemicals in the cell which when they react will produce an emf of 12 V.  The behaviour of real cells as compared with an ideal imperfect cell (constant emf, unlimited chemicals, constant internal resistance) is very much more complex as other chemical reactions within the cell start playing a much more important role.

Comment: let's take a battery of 8V emf. it means 8V is needed to move a charge once round a circuit. If it is charged to 3V assuming it is uncharged then will it be able to take a charge round the whole circuit?If yes can u explain why

Comment: The primary chemical reaction within a cell produces a certain emf which depends on the chemicals involved.  There is no intermediate value.  Other chemical reactions within the cell may change the internal resistance of the cell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48720/discussion-between-mritun-jay-and-farcher).

Comment: Suppose the terminal voltage is 4.8V and EF of it is 5.0V. So if a voltmeter is connected across the battery what will be the reading of voltmeter? Will it be 4.8V or 5.0V
and if u can please explain it